# Token obtained from Azure AD through MSAL expires immediately

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

I implemented authentication with Azure AD using MSAL in my xamarin forms app according to [this blogpost](https://blog.xamarin.com/authenticate-mobile-apps-using-microsoft-authentication-library/).

It seemed to work fine, it gives me the expected login dialog in which I can login with my AD account and returns an AuthenticationResult with an accesstoken.

However when I attempt to use the token my API gives me a 401-Unauthorized.
I've tried using the `[Authorize]` attribute and setting the 'Action to take when request is not authenticated' to 'Login with Azure Active Directory' on my appservice in Azure. But it fails in both cases.

When I check the accesstoken it returns I noticed the ExpiresOn property has the exact DateTime in it of the moment of when i requested my token which whould explain the 401 as the token would be expired immediately.

I've tried to removed the `[Authorize]` and set Azure to Allow all so I could check the `RequestContext.Principal.Identity` in my API but the IsAuthenticated property is false and no other identity properties contain any of my information.

Hopefully someone is able to tell me why my token expires at the time it is acquired or what it is I'm doing wrong as I've been stuck on this for a while now.

My code:

```
PublicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication(authority, clientId);
```

and

```
    public async Task Authenticate()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
        try
        {
            authenticationResult = await App.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            try
            {
                authenticationResult = await App.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                authenticationResult = null;
                App.Logger.LogException(ex);
            }
        }

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            TokenData = new ApiTokenData
            {
                AccessToken = authenticationResult.Token,
                ExpiresAt = authenticationResult.ExpiresOn.UtcDateTime
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally the token expires after 60 minutes. I am wondering if the date/time on the device is somehow not right that is causing the token to expire immediately. Can you please check that?

Comment: I've tried it on both android(device) and locally with UWP and checked the LocalDateTime/UtcDateTime properties of the ExpiresOn(DateTimeOffset), they are all the same DateTime the token was requested on.

Comment: I have the same issue. No clue how to resolve it.